# Install syndesis on Windows when minishift is installed

Tags: windows, syndesis

I have some problems to install syndesis on Windows.

My configuration is Win10 64bits with minishift installed.
*minishift* and *oc* commands works from command line.
I have started the OpenShift server and I can connect it with web browser.

1. I tried the install mentioned README.md with Cygwin: "bash <(curl -sL https://syndes.is/start) --vm-driver hyperkit" --> nothing happen
2. Then I tried the syndesis-cli from [2.0.0-20210514](https://github.com/syndesisio/syndesis/releases/tag/2.0.0-20210514) with Cygwin

> $ ./syndesis install
>
> /cygdrive/d/users/toto/Downloads/syndesis-cli/commands/util/common_funcs: line 354: /home/toto/.syndesis/bin/platform-detect: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
> operator binary not found under /home/toto/.syndesis/bin/syndesis-operator, attempting to download...
>
> OK
>
> Unknown platform [ cygwin ],
>
> unable to download the operator binary, exit
> ERROR: Last command exited with 1

How can I install syndesis on Windows?

Thanks !

Toto